# How to prevent bots from appearing in "Online Customers" in backend?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, backend, filter

Checking the "Online Customers" in Magento's backend shows a lot of bot IP addresses. These bots include bots like google crawler.

Is there a way to filter those out, so I can see only real visitors?

I suppose that might require a list of IP addresses/ranges. For some bots they are publicly available, so I guess that is not a problem.

But how do I actually hide them from the backend? Is there any extension made for this?

EDIT:
Please note:
These are bots I would like to continue accessing my site, so I would not want to block them from accessing my site, so blocking bots is not an option. I simply want to filter the display, so they do not appear in the given list.

(using Magento CE 1.9.1)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent bots from appearing in “Online Customers” backend, you have to add in the file app/code/core/Mage/Log/etc/config.xml the bots you want to get rid of. I have change these lines witch remove most of the bots visitors...

```
<ignore_user_agents>
  <google1>Googlebot/1.0 (googlebot@googlebot.com http://googlebot.com/)</google1>
  <google2>Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)</google2>
  <google3>Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)</google3>
</ignore_user_agents>
```

By

```
<ignore_user_agents>
  <google1>Googlebot/1.0 (googlebot@googlebot.com http://googlebot.com/)</google1>
  <google2>Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)</google2>
  <google3>Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)</google3>
  <google4>Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)</google4>
  <Ahrefs1>Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.2; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)</Ahrefs1>
  <Semrush1>Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/1.2~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)</Semrush1>
  <Bing1>Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)</Bing1>
  <Bing2>Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)</Bing2>
</ignore_user_agents>
```

Do not forget to refresh the System Configuration Cache